# Cachephp 3, options list from table in each page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Cakephp 3.0. I want to show a checkboxes filter for categories in a menu present in each page with an icon as label.

I have a table (model) "category" with id, name, icon, etc. I want to take these fields in a form in the menu, but I do not want to repeat the query in each method of each controller to pass the variable.

I thought to make the query in the view or in a helper, but I did not find the way.

How would you proceed?

Thank you

Comment: Create [Cell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)

Comment: seems the perfect situation for a cell

Comment: Aha! Yes, thank you!!